# Travelling from USA to india through Frankfurt on F1 visa with just 2 months of visa validity

Tags: indian-citizens

I am planning to travel India on march 30 through Lufthansa airlines via Munich and and I will return on April 16, the thing is, my F1 visa valid till June 30,2020 only. are we OK to travel to India via Germany with 80 days of visa validity and I have valid I-20 with Sevis active, I would be more helpful if some one helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what, exactly is being asked.